# Magic the Gathering, when a player dies what happens to their cards?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

Today me and 3 friends were playing Magic, we are all new to it (One guy taught my friend, my friend taught me and his girlfriend, I taught my sister, besides the first guy thats who was playing)

My friend pulled a card that said he got a 1/1 token on his creature for every creature card in everyones graveyard (I don't remember the name sorry!)
So a few turns later I died (Serious mana screw, I never even played a card besides 2 mana, because I couldn't, and one got destroyed by another card, I got killed by multiplie attacks by a tarra stomper xD) so I picked my cards up and started shuffling for when they all 3 finished (I knew it would be a little bit but what else would I do?)
So my friend pulled a card from his deck to replay a card from the graveyard

So he pulled the one to create a 1/1 token on his creature for every creature in the grave yard

This is were the question comes in
Do the creatures in my graveyard (They got there when my hand became full, like I said I never actually played a card not that that part matters) still count even though I died?

We assumed they did and I apologized for messing up, but then jus now I decided to look it up and see if they count
I can't find an answer so Im asking
Sorry if this is a dumb question I've only played 8 or so games before and never ran into this problem so I thought it would be good to know for the future

Sure Im dead but if I'm playing with random people at a shop and I die and need to leave I would feel pretty bad picking up my graveyard if they should be able to use it

Also what about enchantments and such on their creatures that I put there? Does my hand go to the graveyard? What about cards I have down in use / creatures on my battlefield

Someone marked this as a possible duplicate but one thing wasn't really answered in the post
Does my graveyard still effect anything? I didn't see it referenced in the other post, sorry if Im missing something
The other post pretty much answered all my other questions, thanks.
Also add on question, if thats okay (I realize this is not really a forum so Im sorry if adding another question isn't acceptable) where are the full list of rules that person was quoting from in their answer?

Comment: It really is a duplicate. The answer to the linked question explains everything you need to know for when you leave a multiplayer match. Everything you own leaves the game, of course that includes cards in the graveyard, and none of your cards count for anything in the ongoing game as soon as you leave the game. You don't have to stick around until the game ends. As for your second question, the comprehensive rules can be found here: http://archive.wizards.com/Magic/tcg/article.aspx?x=magic/rules

Comment: Okay thank you! I'm sorry, should I remove my question or what? Im not really sure how things work around here sorry.

Comment: No need to be sorry, everybody has been new to this at some point, and you are already showing more desire to improve than most new users. You can remove questions/answers, but don't have to, that's what user moderation is for. If someone else for some reason finds your question instead of the original, your question would be a kind of redirect, so 2 pages is better than 1. If you want to stick around for more question and want to contribute, you are very welcome to. Take the quick tour if you are unsure how things work: http://boardgames.stackexchange.com/tour Welcome to the site!